# Obtener un valor y enviarlo como parametro con Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un pills tab de boostrap y obtengo el dato del `aria-controls` al hacer clic en el enlace de cada `nav-link`, podría tomar el `year`, necesito enviar ese valor a un controlador laravel para hacer una consulta y devolver la colección a la vista, con ajax.

```
@foreach($videos as $video)

  <li class="nav-item" id="link-front">
    <a class="nav-link @if($loop->last) show active @endif"   id="{{ $video->year }}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $video->year }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ $video->year }}" aria-selected="@if($loop->first) true @else false @endif">{{ $video->year }}</a>
  </li>

@endforeach
```

Estoy construyendo el script pero no tengo mucha idea de como lograrlo:

```
<script>
   $("a").on('click', function (e) {
      var year = $(this).attr("aria-controls");
      console.log(year)
   });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{route('index')}}",
        data: year,
        success: function(data) {
      }
    });
</script>
```

Puedo leer la variable `year` en la función del clic, pero no en el ajax `data: year`, dice que no está definida.

Comment: Ajax no te va a meter en la URL parametros de tipo GET que es supongo lo que deseas, puedes usar un formulario normal sin usar AJAX para eso o modificar tu directamente la URL poniendole esos datos, pero AJAX no va a modificarte la URL.

Comment: Okey, y como puedo obtener ese dato para luego enviarlo por formulario?

Comment: Lo que necesito es enviarlo al controlador para que me regrese una consulta

Comment: "si hago clic en profile www.miweb.com/profile y recargar la página para poder obtener la consulta" me parece que enrealidad lo que deseas es enviar los datos y una vez enviados redirigir al usuario a la pagina manteniendo los datos, este es el comportamiento por defecto de un formulario y los input del form almacenarian la data. Dejame entender algo... una ultima pregunta, tu problema es que no sabes de que manera  puedes recoger informacion que ya tienes en tu HTML para poder enviar estos datos a otra pagina??, si es asi en unos minutos doy mi respuesta.

Comment: correcto, debo obtener el valor del nav-link para luego hacer una consulta a la bd con ese dato, pensé que enviándolo por GET sería mejor, ya que defino en la ruta la variable y la recibo en el controlador, pero podría hacerlo por mediode POST usando ajax yevitando la recarga de la página, ya que la respuesta la requiero en la misma web www.miweb.com

Comment: De hecho debes tener en cuenta que pese a ser ajax una tecnologia muy poderosa normalmente se usa es para usar los datos en la misma pagina y prevenir tener que recargar la pagina o redirigirte a otra, si al fin y al cabo deseas ir a la otra pagina, entonces es mejor opcion simplemente no usarlo (usar un formulario comun y corriente a la antigua).

Comment: Que raro, el codigo no me quiere funcionar muy bien, habrán roto algo en jQuery?, porque estoy probando tu codigo y el script se congela y después de un tiempo funciona aqui en stackoverflow.

Comment: El código no está funcionando

Comment: No, lo digo porque literalmente se me congela la pagina cuando lo ejecuto aunque le quite la llamada a ajax xd. que cosas mas curiosas...

Comment: La verdad sí, porque solo es ese html y el Ajax, a menos que haya escrito algo que en el ajax que lo haga colgarse, pero a mi nome pasa

Comment: Ya veo, laravel.

Comment: Sí :) necesito cambiar el contenido dependiendo del enlace que seleccione el usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la data de tus elementos con la clase `nav-link`:

```js
const data = {};
const contents = Array.from($(".nav-link")).map(el => {
  data[$(el).attr("aria-controls")] = $(el).text();
  return data;
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">...3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">...4</div>
</div>
```

Lo que he hecho aquí:

```
const data = {};
const contents = Array.from($(".nav-link")).map(el => {
  data[$(el).attr("aria-controls")] = $(el).text();
  return data;
});
console.log(data);
```

Es crear un objeto `data` que será rellenado pasandole como clave el valor que contenga cada atributo `"aria-controls"` en cada `nav-link` que tengas, y como valor el contenido de texto de cada `nav-link` si deseas añadir mas propiedades quitar algunas o no era exactamente la info que deseabas extraer puedes modificarlo a gusto haciendo uso de mi ejemplo.

Esta data será la que deberás colocar en:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./",      //La url deberia ser ./
  data: data,     //Aquí
  success: function(data) {
  console.log(data.href)
}
```

De esta forma estarías enviando un `JSON` hacia la misma pagina parecido a este por medio de `POST` (le cambie el method a `POST`):

```
{
  "home": "Home",
  "profile": "Profile",
  "messages": "Messages",
  "settings": "Settings"
}
```

De todas maneras:

> Ten en cuenta que la idea de enviar datos hacia el servidor es para
>   que te respondan con otros datos distintos, si tu idea es enviar los
>   datos hacia la misma pagina tu pagina debe encargarse de enviar una
>   respuesta (para recibir estos datos en ajax) y a la vez ser la
>   estructura, lo cual no es para nada aconsejable.
>
> Te recomiendo que en vez de enviar datos a la misma pagina simplemente
>   separes la logica de `PHP` a otro archivo aparte, si no estas usando
>   algo del lado del servidor como `PHP` o `NodeJS` del lado del servidor
>   entonces tienes serios problemas.
>
> De todas maneras ten en cuenta que ajax **NO** recarga la pagina ni te
>   envia a esta, por lo que aunque tu archivo este aparte siempre
>   puedes recibir una respuesta en el mismo archivo en el `success` de
>   ajax.

Si no usas ningún lenguaje del servidor para procesar la data enviada a por ejemplo `PHP` o `nodejs` no pienses que tu archivo `index.html` podra ser usado como receptor de tus datos en `ajax` y a la vez como servidor, si tu idea era no tener que aprender algun lenguaje del lado del servidor para realizar estos procesos, deberas si o si aprender aunque sea un lenguaje del lado del servidor.

De lo contrario la data simplemente será rechazada en tu archivo a la hora de enviarla o `ajax` dará un error de conexión al servidor.

Esto es diferente si tu archivo tiene extensión `.php` la cual ya si seria valida para recibir estas peticiones **si corre por ejemplo en un servidor local**.

Si no corre en un servidor ya sea `local` o no definitivamente el archivo y ajax nunca te van a funcionar para el propósito de recepción y procesamiento de datos.

Comment: Por supuesto decir de antemano que hacer post a las rutas de los controladores si es una de tus opciones no funcionara, las rutas manejadas por angular, ionic o ciertos frameworks de ese estilo no pueden usarse para hacer peticiones post de manera directa, deben ser peticiones a rutas de archivos y no de componentes o paginas directas de la aplicacion, por ejemplo hacer post a http:www.miweb.com/#home si se trata de angular, react o incluso vue no es posible, pero algo como: http:www.miweb.com/recibir.php si que es posible.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder... Te aclaro mejor lo que necesito, antes me gustaría decirte que el código que me diste funciona pero me trae todos los 'aria-controls' y necesito obtener el del enlace al que se le hace clic, de manera que pueda enviar ese dato, en este caso un año, al controlador y devolver una consulta eloquenta la vista.

Comment: Y obtener el año en el objeto: year:2016 o year:2017

Comment: Esos datos year y demas no se encuentran en el codigo que pusiste... considera editar la pregunta para yo editar mi respuesta y añadir una posible solución.

Comment: Ya lo logré obtener, ya edito la pregunta si no logro llevarlo al controlador o devolver la consulta.

Comment: El contenido del atributo  'aria-controls'  es un año

Comment: El contenido de aria-controls en el codigo de tu pregunta no son años xd.

Comment: cierto, solo que allí va una variable, disculpa.

Comment: Listo, modifiqué la pregunta y agregué mi código con el ajax modificado también. Creo que se entiende mejor.